# Runtime error in ntdll on Windows XP running g++

Tags: c++, g++, ntdll

So I have this cpp file, a constructor to my cl_Page class.

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_SoftRoot *parent_param)/* : bgimage(nullptr)*/{
    parent_softroot = parent_param;
    parent_type = 2;
    id[0] = '\0';
    SetColor(bgcolor, 0xffffffff);
    //textboxes.resize(0);
    //buttons.resize(0);
    //images.resize(0);
}
```

The problem is that even before the constructor starts running (the parent_softroot is not yet set) my program crashes. The call stack looks like this:

```
#0 77C460CB strcat() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll:??)
#1 7C9140BB ntdll!RtlDosApplyFileIsolationRedirection_Ustr() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#2 00401905 cl_Page::cl_Page(this=0x738a58, parent_param=0x737810) (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\classes\soft_tree\page.cpp:10)
#3 00402195 cl_SoftRoot::cl_SoftRoot(this=0x737810) (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\classes\soft_tree\softroot.cpp:4)
#4 004031F4 p2_parse_root(parent_x=0x22bdc0) (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\parser\parser.cpp:166)
#5 00402D64 parser_wrapper(filename=0x47c1f2 "Test_Software.xml") (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\parser\parser.cpp:24)
#6 00402BB8 main() (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\main.cpp:12)
```

The cl_Page constructor is called using an initializer list in the cl_SoftRoot constructor.

I'll be glad to supply any information required.

EDIT: The cl_Page class header:

```
 class cl_Page{
    public:
    cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param);
    cl_Page(cl_SoftRoot *parent_param);
    int parent_type;
    cl_LessonMoment *parent_lmoment;
    cl_SoftRoot *parent_softroot;

    char id[256]; //identification

    //<content>
    //Backgrounds.
    str_Color bgcolor;
    cl_Image bgimage;

    //Actual content
    vector<cl_Textbox> textboxes;
    vector<cl_Button> buttons;
    vector<cl_Image> images;
    //</content>

    cl_Textbox* AddTextbox();
    cl_Button* AddButton();
    cl_Image* AddImage(char *filename = nullptr);
};
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Did you step into the code?

Comment: Could you post the clPage class definition?

Comment: Satuton: I do know how to use it. It's just useless because this constructor is only called once in my program so far. It's very linear as it stands. The call stack just traces everything just as I expected.

Comment: I suspect the "ntdll!..." is a bogus label, and the real problem is that you are trying to conactenate a string that is pointing nowhere sane.

Comment: Mats Petersson: No. I'm not calling any stcat() or ntdll!... I guess it's because of the OS.

Comment: Is this a debug or release build?

Comment: Matteo: Debug build. This means -g is checked and no -0 is checked.